# Wood: A Naturally Occurring Composite Material?

Tags: material-science

In materials science texts, I see wood used an example of a naturally occurring composite material. One of the main components of wood is cellulose, which is a polymer. But what other component makes it a composite?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: This question is answered in the 2nd sentence of the Wikipedia article on [wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood).

Comment: @ThePhoton Perhaps I misunderstood the definition of composite. Is a material with two types of polymers considered a composite? Or must it the material contain a type of polymer with a type of ceramic and/or metal? My understanding is that lignin and cellulose are both polymers.

Comment: If this is for a class, that might depend on exactly what definition is given in your class. Wikipedia just [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_material) the component materials should have "significantly different physical or chemical properties".

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm reading the textbook *Materials Science and Engineering* by William Callister and David Rethwisch. It says the following: *A composite is composed of two (or more) individual materials that come from the categories previously discussed -- metals, ceramics, and polymers.* I thought that meant that the material must be at least from 2 of those 3 categories, but I might have interpreted it incorrectly? It might mean that it can be 2 polymers, 2 metals, 2 ceramics, etc.?

Comment: No, all of the components can belong to the same 'category' (e.g. metal-metal composites).

Comment: @lemon Ahh, ok. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the two components of wood-as-a-composite are cellulose fibers and *lignin*, the resin in which the cellulose fibers are embedded. Cellulose furnishes strength in tension and the resin furnishes strength in shear.